# What options do I have to receive restitution from a company that defrauded me and was convicted in 2004?

Tags: fraud, restitution

I was defrauded in 2004 by a company and all the members of that company have been in jail after being convicted in court.  I saw that they were ordered to pay restitution, which I never received.  Some years back I got a check from the postmaster or treasury or some federal organization for $42 which I think was from this case.  I was defrauded approximately $18,000.  How did these criminals get out of paying restitution?  Do I have any rights to that money today if I never cashed that check from before?

I was thinking about this because I got an email update from the US Department of Justice about one of the inmates going on a furlough.

Are there any options to sue?

Comment: What state? There might be a state agency that manages restitution orders.

Comment: Florida is the state I and the company were in

Comment: You may want to re-work this question so that it is in a hypothetical format rather than seeking specific legal advice. Also, you should note What exactly they were convicted of, whether you (john doe) testified, whether evidence was given pertaining to Doe's alleged defrauding, whether the judgment refers to Doe as a victim, whether Doe was contacted by victim witness services and afforded counseling about rights of restitution. Also important will be if the corporate veil was pierced and the individuals were held individually liable for defrauding Doe.